# EclipseでRを使う

Tags: java, r

EclipseでRを使いたいのですが、なかなかうまくいきません。
正確には、Rでかけるグラフをjavaのプログラム上で書きたいため、Rをjavaで呼びたいと考えて、調べたところJRIかRServeを使わなければいけないとのことです。
やり方を調べましたが、古いものが多く、その通りに行かないことだ多々あったので質問させていただきました。

Comment: "古いものが多く、その通りに行かないことだ多々あったので質問させていただきました。"の具体的な内容を書かないと、回答できないのでは。。。ざっくり「私のやりたいことをだれか代わりにやってほしい」なのでしょうか。JavaからRを使うのはできていてEclpseでさらにコーディングしたいのか、そもそもJava⇒Rの呼び出しができていないのか。。。後者なら、タイトルと状況は異なります。

Comment: わかりにくくて申し訳ないです。ざっくり行ってしまうとJava⇒Rの呼び出しの呼び出しをする方法を教えていただきたいのです。

Comment: 他の質問内容みましたが、この問題は解決しましたか？

Comment: はい、解決しました。教えてくださりありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とりあえず、R、Rtool、RStudio、JRIインストールしてjavaからRのsqrtを使える状態を作ってみました。。こんなことがしたいのでいいでしょうか？（java.library.pathを使って何とかしようとしたけど、結局環境変数PATHに頼ってしまったのは内緒です。）

プロジェクト一式をgithubにあげておいたのでよければcloneしてください。mavenプロジェクトにしたので、eclipseでもIntelliJでも、NetBeansでも使えますが、動作確認はNetBeansのみです。。Eclipseの場合はファイル⇒インポート⇒既存のMavenプロジェクトをインポート（最近使ってないのでうろ覚え）を使えば、コンパイルと実行ができるような気がします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
https://github.com/atowaito/sample/tree/master/SampleRProject